# Get filename of Record in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is it possible to get the filename of a record in Hive? That would be incredibly helpful for debugging.

In my particular case, I've an incorrect values ​​in a table that is mapped to a folder with > 100 large files. To use grep is very inefficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HIVE` supports virtual columns, for example `INPUT__FILE__NAME`. It gives the input file's name for a mapper task.

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns). It provides some example on how to do this.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to test the same now. Let me know if this is working or not.